# Background Task in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have a Laravel Application that has a function for create and download PDF, i using DOMPDF. It's ok but in production (Heroku), this operation sometimes takes a long time, more than the 30 seconds expected by Heroku, for this reason I get a timeout error.
As Heroku suggested:

> we recommend moving that work to a background task or worker to
> periodically ping your server to see if the processing request has
> been finished

I should implement the background operation, what is the best way to do it in Laravel?

Is Queues on external service like Amazon SQS, Beanstalk, or Redis, the best solution?

Comment: Yes, in general, queues are a good way to handle this.

Comment: is an AJAX call a valid solution?

Comment: No, AJAX calls are subject to the same 30 second timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You have to put your function (create_and_download_pdf) in a Job, then use queue:work command line to execute that job. Take look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#introduction to know how to make it.